# How to send dynamic data to c3chart angular line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I want to draw a line chart which updates itself on an event and loads new data `onClick`.

Here is the way I'm drawing the chart in HTML :

```
<c3chart bindto-id="{{key}}" padding-left="20" 
     padding-right="20" padding-top="20" padding-bottom="20"  
           chart-data="lineChartData[key]" chart-columns="lineChartColumns[key]" 
                                                            chart-x="lineChartX">
   <chart-size chart-width="250" chart-height="270"/>
   <chart-legend  show-legend="false" legend-position="right"/>
   <chart-events on-click-data="onChange(key,data)"></chart-events>
</c3chart>
```

In the controller, i'm defining the variables as follow:

```
var chartPoints = {};
var chartColumns = [];
var chartPointsArr = [];
var chartLinePts = [];
var chartXAxis =[];

showData.forEach(function(s) {
    if (s.number) {

        chartLinePts.push(s.count);
        chartXAxis.push(s.number);
     }
});

chartPoints["data"] = chartLinePts;
chartPoints["x"] = chartXAxis;
chartPointsArr.push(chartPoints);

var chartColumnEntry = {};
chartColumnEntry['id'] = "data";
chartColumnEntry['type'] = 'line';
chartColumns.push(chartColumnEntry);


console.log(chartPointsArr);
console.log(chartColumns);

$scope.lineChartData[key] = chartPointsArr;
$scope.lineChartColumns[key] = chartColumns;
$scope.lineChartX = {"id":"x","name":"data"};
```

When I print `lineChartData`, `lineChartColumns` and `lineChartX` in HTML, I get the following :

```
[{"data":[100,500,200,400,100],"x":[0,10,20,30,40]}]

[{"id":"data","type":"line"}]

{"id":"x","name":"data"}
```

But this data does not draw the chart and I get an error saying :

```
d3.js:669 Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN, 0)"
```

I understand that `d3` is not getting valid data to draw the chart. Hence I would like to know the correct way to pass the dynamic data to line chart.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at few resources, I found that one of the ways to send data to c3chart for plotting line chart is as shown below:

```
var chartColumns = [];
var chartPointsArr = [];
var chartXAxis =[];

showData.forEach(function(s) {
    if (s.number) {

        var chartPoints = {};
        chartPoints["data"] = s.count;
        chartPoints["x"] = s.number;

        chartPointsArr.push(chartPoints);
     }
});

var chartColumnEntry = {};
chartColumnEntry['id'] = "data";
chartColumnEntry['type'] = 'line';
chartColumns.push(chartColumnEntry);

$scope.lineChartData[key] = chartPointsArr;
$scope.lineChartColumns[key] = chartColumns;
$scope.lineChartX = {"id":"x","name":"data"};
```

So when I printed it in HTML it looks like :

```
{"data":100,"x":0},{"data":500,"x":10},{"data":200,"x":20},{"data":400,"x":30},{"data":100,"x":40}]

[{"id":"data","type":"line"}]
```